# OpenGL camera movement issue

Tags: opengl, 3d, rotation, quaternions, glm-math

I'm having a problem rotating my yaw-pitch camera. I had the camera working great, except for when looking either straight up or straight down. Taking the cross product for getting the right-vector would crash the program while looking up because I was originally crossing my forward-vector (0, 1, 0) with the world-up vector (0, 1, 0). To fix this, I decided I would calculate the right-vector by taking the cross product of the forward-vector and my up-vector (which would imply that I would also need to update my up-vector). I'm getting weird results with this code that, to me, would make sense:

```
glm::quat quaternion = glm::angleAxis(angle.x, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));

forward = glm::rotate(quaternion, forward); // change yaw

glm::vec3 right = glm::cross(forward, up);

quaternion = glm::angleAxis(angle.y, right);

forward = glm::rotate(quaternion, forward); // change pitch

up = glm::cross(right, forward); // update up-vector, unintended result
```

I call `up = glm::cross(right, forward)` to update my camera's up-vector, so that if I were to point the camera directly up, I could safely take `glm::vec3 right = glm::cross(forward, up)` to get my right-vector for pitch rotation. However, this code causes my camera to rotate my up-vector sideways, which I do not want. All help appreciated.

So in short, how do I recalculate my camera's up-vector so that I can use it for calculating my camera's right vector with a cross product?

Edit: To clarify, `up = glm::cross(right, forward)` for some reason, makes my camera "roll". I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Do you initialize `forward` to something like `(0, 0, -1)`?

Comment: Yeah, thats initialized. If I take this `up = glm::cross(right, forward)` out of my code, the camera functions properly as a flying yaw-pitch camera.

Comment: Are you saving some state? Or are `forward`, `right` and `up` always calculated fresh from the beginning? You calculate `right` before calculating `up` why would you then recalculate `right` as a cross product? What do you mean by "the up-vector is rotated sideways"?

Comment: I'm using `glm::lookAt()` with `position`, `forward` and `up`. The states are all saved in the Camera class, this function just updates those vectors so that I can move with yaw and pitch. I calculate `right` with the cross product of `forward` and `up`, because if I instead calculated it with `forward` and `(0, 1, 0)`, taking the cross product would potentially crash the program. I recalculate `up`, because if I didn't it would always stay as `(0, 1, 0)`. Finally, when I say "the up-vector is rotated sideways", I mean that my camera is tilted on its forward axis (the camera flips upside down)

Comment: Your calculations should not be based on updated vectors. Especially the `forward` vector should always be something like `(0, 0, -1)` and the up-vector should always be something like `(0, 1, 0)`. Rotating vectors that have already been rotated is a bit hard to manage.